# Argon to store chemicals?

Tags: chemicals

I have a tank of argon for my TIG welder. 
I was wondering, if I use dark glass bottles and fill the air space with argon, will the solutions keep longer? will it be the same as floating lids/accordeon bottles? I don't have any of those.

Comment: Don't forget to store in the dark, in a cold environment (fridge). I haven't seen much data, but I would suspect light and temp to do more harm than availability of oxygen in the bottle. Removing all three seems like a trifecta for long term stability

Comment: @Hueco I would not generally advice to store photo chemicals in a fridge. Many products, at least undiluted concentrates, are so saturated that they will crystallize if stored much below room temperature. Depending on the composition of the chemicals, the crystals may not be able to dissolve, even if the solution is warmed up again.

Comment: @jarnbjo to each their own. Sounds like you may have run into people storing things too cold. I lived in AZ for some time. Fridge set to 45-50F > room temp (80F summer) and definitely > garage temp (120F summer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitrogen is normally used because it is inert, so is argon, you should be OK. Aside from the liquid air junction, these fluids contain dissolved gases, which incudes oxygen. Nitrogen or argon, should act to lengthen the shelf life of stored chemicals. However, father time works it's dirty deed.

Comment: Yes, nitrogen is the usual. But since I already have an argon tank at home I thought I'd try it instead. Nitrogen I'd have to buy, but if I were to buy stuff, I might as well buy proper tanks,

Comment: No special tanks needed.  https://www.amazon.com/Private-Preserve-Wine-Preservation-Spray/dp/B0000DCS18  I use it in my darkroom and my wine, sometimes at the same time ;) I also cook with wine and sometimes i put it in the food.

Answer (score 1):

Remember Oxygen is already dissolved in the solution, so unless you're bubbling nitrogen through it to de-oxygenate it you're going to burn up all of the oxygen scavenger in liquid form far before the O2 starts making it across the thin film.

It'll help, but more importantly- don't mix it until you need it.

Comment: Yeah the plan is to keep the concentrates in the bottles and use as needed, and top off with inert gas.